# Arduino Wifi/Wemos Wifi D1 adding &t=0 to simple GET request

Tags: wifi, esp8266

I'm attempting to make a simple get request to my website from my arduino, but I'm unable to do so.

I keep getting the following error:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://dnserrorassist.att.net/search/?q=http://www.example.com/&t=0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.location="http://dnserrorassist.att.net/search/?q="+escape(window.location)+"&r="+escape(document.referrer)+"&t=0";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Edit: Here's the important code.

```
const char http_site[] = "www.example.com";
const int http_port = 80;

// Perform an HTTP GET request to a remote page
bool getPage() {

  // Attempt to make a connection to the remote server
  if ( !client.connect('http://' + http_site, http_port) ) {
    return false;
  } else 
  {
    Serial.println("Connected!");
  }

  // Make an HTTP GET request
  client.print("GET /");
  Serial.print("GET /");

  client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
  Serial.println(" HTTP/1.1");

  client.println("Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1995");
  Serial.println("Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1995");

  client.println("Connection: close\r\n");
  Serial.println("Connection: close\r\n");

  return true;
}

void loop(void){

  if ( client.available() ) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an error to me. Can you give more detail? What is your code?

Comment: That's very true. It looks like a URL parameter is being added, but I'm not adding it anywhere.

Comment: It may not like the IP address in the "Host:" line. See [3.2.2 http URL](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.2)

Comment: Hey, I figured it out. It didn't like two things: 1. the IP in the Host, and 2. http:// in the client.connect.

Comment: `client.println("Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1995")` sounds wrong to me. It should be either `client.println("Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")` or better `client.println("Host: www.example.com")`

Comment: @Gerben, yes. You're right. I had to change that to the host I was calling. I've never worked with this stuff before, so it's been quite the learning experience :)

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: what ide do you use? is that in arduino ide?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Arduino IDE.